# How to index across multiple lines within a csv document using python?

Tags: python, list, csv, indexing

for example:

text.csv
John, 3, green
Amy, 6, red
Franky, 2, blue

how would I retrieve any of those individual values, or preferrably: how would I retrieve all the numbers or all the names etc.

i tried using

```
x = open ('text.csv')
for i in x:
    print (x.readline())

x.close()
```

and similar stuff, all of which just printed every line and the entire line.

Comment: Of course, it prints the lines - that's what you've told it to do. If you want to get names or numbers you need to parse those lines instead of just printing them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

try to use the csv module, here you can specify the `delimiter`

```
import csv

with open("./text.csv'", 'r') as file:
  csvreader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',') # "," is also the default
  for row in csvreader:
    print(row)
```

Afterwards you can determine rather `row` is a number, name, color, ect.
For example:

```
if isinstance(row, int): 
  # do stuff with a number
  pass
```

there are better ways to do this as well.

Comment: A good suggestion to use `csv` module. But this doesn't answer the question. And a side note: `','` is the default delimiter of `csv.reader`.